# Cannot get my certificate to work in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008, ssl-certificate

I recently received a wildcard server certificate in the form of a pfx file. I installed the server certificate into the mmc and I've selected it from iis. I've then bound this certificate to a website. I've bound it on 443 on all Unassigned and placed the domain in the host header.

Under mmc the friendly name for the certificate is "*.mydomin.org.uk"

In order to allow access to the application pool I've run winhttocertcfg.exe -g -a "servername\app-pool" -c LOCAL_MACHINE\My -s "*.mydomin.org.uk"

This appeared to work but still every time I try to access the site the page times out and I get no response at all.

I need to be able to get to the site beta.mydomain.org.uk but for some reason it is not responding

Any ideas?

Comment: you are able to access the site through HTTP normally?

Comment: Yes, thanks for responding. I can indeed contact the site through regular http

Comment: When you run `inetmgr` and edit the bindings on your website, the `https` is all setup?

Comment: Thanks oh cheesy one. This is a good response but I should have checked that the external firewall wasn't blocking it. Which is what the actual problem was. Good suggestion though and it might help some other poor soul with similar problems. Tar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where specifically did you install the certificate? If you installed it under personal certificates for current user that won’t work.

Open MMC add these two snap-ins and see if this is the case.

[image]

Also make sure you checked for misc things such as port on the firewall and such.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed the firewall port. I worked this out a couple of days ago. I just forgot to update my response because I am naughty. Awesome response though dude. Thanks